# How to translate code from python2 to python3 using lib2to3

Tags: python, python-3.x

If anyone can explain this. In the python documents it says that it is indeed possible. [PythonLib2to3 Resource](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html#module-lib2to3)

Note that I am also using pycharm. If that helps at all

Comment: Why do you want to use `lib2to3` instead of just the `2to3` tool?

Comment: I'm just seeking out information. I am glad you brought this up is the 22to3 tool a module?

Comment: `lib2to3` is a python module which the command line tool `2to3` is based on.

Comment: Well, do you think you can help me. I am reading some python code from python2, but I am trying to translate it into python3, due to the fact that I am using python3 instead of 2. I could learn to use 2, however, I'd rather not given the fact that I have become so engrossed in 3 already.

Comment: Scroll to the top of the page you linked to and there's a tutorial on how to use 2to3.